# Is there any open source malware removal app for Android?

Tags: android, open-source, malware

Please let me know! When it comes to harvesting personal data, gratis closed source antimalware apps are among the worst offenders.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is not. But you probably wouldn't even need it if you'd stick to safe, open source Android apps in general – and use [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) instead of Playstore. You can find out more about that here: [F-Droid: The privacy-friendly alternative to Google Play Store](https://android.izzysoft.de/catmin/articles/named/fdroid-intro-1) (Disclosure: I'm one of the F-Droid maintainers, and that link goes to my Android website)

Comment: Sound advice which I'll follow in future. Unfortunately I'm already afflicted, so I need to either remove the malware somehow or reflash the phone :/

Comment: Afraid it will be the latter – if you want to be half-way sure you really killed everything of that stuff :(

Comment: Oh, of course you can only be sure that way. But antimalware has its place too